# Intellisense treating .c file as .cpp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I am using VS2010 for a C project. I keep getting Intellisense errors `IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Blah *"`, which is true for C++, but is perfectly legal in C, which leads me to believe that Intellisense can only parse C++, and is doing so even on my C files. The other option is that my c files are being treated as c++ files (the icon in the project explorer is the c++ icon, not a c icon), but this is not likely as actually compiling works fine. Only the Intellisense is getting it wrong, not the compiler.

Comment: C++ (and C) are the stepchildren of VS.  WE c++ developers are being left behind - it is clear that all new development and the focus of the product is C#/.NET.  You might look for third party tools for this - like Whole Tomato or perhaps other ones.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be to restart my project and just copy over my files. I've had VS2010 mess up on me before for no discernible reason. Probably just one small piece of incorrect data. but starting the project over has worked for me in the past. :) Best of luck!