# How to exclude cpp related files from VS code, via C/C++ intellisense (including/indexing) when compiling .c/.h files on windows msvc

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, cmake

- New to msvc building and vs code
- Trying to build a *.c & *.h set of files, but get errors as though I'm trying to compile them as *.cpp & *.hpp files, as the errors show below.
- I'm not quite sure I completely understand what intellisense is doing for me, but it appears that is wants to index, process, include, and compile files not needed for c files.
- There appears to be a way to exclude files, but that seems a little too involved to have to try and exclude every file that is meant for cpp
- cmake tools installed/used

cmake build [Visual Studio Community 2019 Release - amd64], windows 10

```
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build x:/xxxx/xxx/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -- /maxcpucount:10
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

settings.json:

```
    "C_Cpp.loggingLevel": "Debug",
    "cmake.loggingLevel": "debug",
    "files.associations": {
    "*.h": "c"
    }
```

c_cpp_properties.h

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "x:/xxxx/xxxx/**"
            ],
            "compilerArgs": [],
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "x:/xxxx/xxxx/**"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
```

Here is the debug c/c++ output

```
Custom browse configuration received: {
  "browsePath": [
    "x:/xxx/xxx/"
  ],
  "standard": "c++17",
  "compilerPath": "c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/buildtools/vc/tools/msvc/14.25.28610/bin/hostx86/x86/cl.exe",
  "compilerArgs": [
    "/DWIN32",
    "/D_WINDOWS",
    "/W3",
    "/MD",
    "/Zi",
    "/O2",
    "/Ob1",
    "/DNDEBUG",
    "/W4"
  ]
}
cpptools/didChangeCppProperties
Attempting to get defaults from compiler found on the machine: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe'
Code browsing service initialized
Attempting to get defaults from compiler found on the machine: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe'
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO/2019/COMMUNITY/VC/TOOLS/MSVC/14.26.28801/INCLUDE/* will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO/2019/COMMUNITY/VC/TOOLS/MSVC/14.26.28801/ATLMFC/INCLUDE/* will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/UM/ will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/UCRT/ will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/SHARED/ will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/WINRT/ will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/CPPWINRT/ will be indexed
  Folder: x:/xxx/xxxx/ will be indexed
cpptools/didChangeCustomBrowseConfiguration
Attempting to get defaults from compiler found on the machine: 'c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/buildtools/vc/tools/msvc/14.25.28610/bin/hostx86/x86/cl.exe'
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO/2019/BUILDTOOLS/VC/TOOLS/MSVC/14.25.28610/INCLUDE/* will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO/2019/BUILDTOOLS/VC/TOOLS/MSVC/14.25.28610/ATLMFC/INCLUDE/* will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/UM/ will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/UCRT/ will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/SHARED/ will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/WINRT/ will be indexed
  Folder: C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/CPPWINRT/ will be indexed
  Folder: x:/xxx/xxxx/ will 
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
Populate include completion cache.
Discovering files...
  Processing folder (non-recursive): C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO/2019/BUILDTOOLS/VC/TOOLS/MSVC/14.25.28610/INCLUDE
  Processing folder (non-recursive): C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO/2019/BUILDTOOLS/VC/TOOLS/MSVC/14.25.28610/ATLMFC/INCLUDE
  Processing folder (recursive): C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/UM/
  Processing folder (recursive): C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/UCRT/
  Processing folder (recursive): C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/SHARED/
  Processing folder (recursive): C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/WINRT/
  Processing folder (recursive): C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.18362.0/CPPWINRT/
  Processing folder (recursive): x:/xxx/VCPKG/INSTALLED/X64-WINDOWS/INCLUDE/
  Discovering files: 28489 file(s) processed
  0 file(s) removed from database
Done discovering files.
Parsing remaining files...
  Parsing: 0 files(s) processed
Done parsing remaining files.
```

and then I get these errors as a results:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\cstdio(33,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cstdio(33,1): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cstdio(33,1): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cstdio(91,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cwchar(22,17): warning C4431: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C no longer supports default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cwchar(22,17): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cwchar(22,17): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '='
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cwchar(24,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cwchar(24,1): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cwchar(24,1): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\cwchar(97,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\type_traits(440,33): error C4233: nonstandard extension used: '__is_union' keyword only supported in C++, not C
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\type_traits(443,41): error C4233: nonstandard extension used: '__is_union' keyword only supported in C++, not C
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\type_traits(447,33): error C4233: nonstandard extension used: '__is_class' keyword only supported in C++, not C
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\type_traits(450,41): error C4233: nonstandard extension used: '__is_class' keyword only supported in C++, not C
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\type_traits(468,39): error C4233: nonstandard extension used: '__is_convertible_to' keyword only supported in C++, not C
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\include\type_traits(473,47): error C4233: nonstandard extension used: '__is_convertible_to' keyword only supported in C++, not C
```

Comment: similar question from 8 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917495/intellisense-treating-c-file-as-cpp

Comment: added ```"files.exclude": {"cstdio": true}``` to settings.json, and re-load, with no change.  However, I just found out that files.exclude only impacts files within ${workspaceFolder}, not external.

Comment: I tried building in visual studio community, same result... so it must be some default values with "cl.exe"?